# Are java enum variables static?

Tags: java, enums

```
public enum Operations {

    SINGLE,
    MULTIPLE;

    private Type operation;

    public void setOperation(Type operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    public Type getOperation() {
        return operation;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Operations oper1 = Operations.SINGLE;
        oper1.setOperation(Type.GET);

        Operations oper2 = Operations.SINGLE;
        oper2.setOperation(Type.POST);
        System.out.println(oper1.getOperation());
        System.out.println(oper2.getOperation());
    }
}

enum Type {
    POST,
    GET;
}
```

In the above code, the value of operation changes for both the Operations. How can I have two instances of Operations.SINGLE with different operation type?

Comment: Your question would be easier to understand if you told us what was printed to stdout. (I assume it prints `POST` twice?)

Comment: SINGLE is equivalent to public static final Operations SINGLE = new Operations("SINGLE", 0)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, instances are implicitly `static` and `final`.  This means that the code is unwise.  Imagine two threads both calling `SINGLE.setOperation(Type)`; you will have no confidence in what you are calling.

From the [Java Language Specification, Section 8.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9):

> Enum types (§8.9) must not be declared abstract; doing so will result in a compile-time error.
>
> An enum type is implicitly final unless it contains at least one enum constant that has a class body.
>
> It is a compile-time error to explicitly declare an enum type to be final.
>
> Nested enum types are implicitly static. It is permissible to explicitly declare a nested enum type to be static.

And in the next section:

> The body of an enum type may contain enum constants. An enum constant defines an instance of the enum type.
>
> Because there is only one instance of each enum constant, it is permissible to use the == operator in place of the equals method when comparing two object references if it is known that at least one of them refers to an enum constant.

Answer (score 11):

> How can I have two instances of Operations.SINGLE with different operation type?

The fundamental idea behind an `enum` is that there is one, and only one, instance of each of its members. This is what lets you safely compare them for equality, without fear that there's another `SINGLE` or `MULTIPLE` created in some other place.

If you want multiple instances of `SINGLE`, make it a `class`, not an `enum`. The fact that you made your `enum` mutable indirectly points in the same direction: using `enum` is a wrong choice in your situation.

Answer (score 10):

Enum instances are "static" (ie behave like static variables), but are not [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

All threads see the same object referred to by the enum name - they are like singletons, with an iron-clad guarantee from the JVM that there is only ever one instance of an enum. Changing a field of an enum changes it for everyone.

It is good practice to make your fields `final` in an enum and to make them immutable.

Answer (score 2):

I'm one year and a half too late. But I see the question was not really answered.

The solution would be using a class instead of enum, that has those two enums as its fields:

```
class Operation {
    Quantity quantity;
    Type type;
    Operation(Quantity quantity, Type type) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

You can, of course, use enum instead of class. Then you'll have to enumerate all combinations:

```
enum Operation {
    SINGLE_GET(Quantity.SINGLE, Type.GET)
    SINGLE_POST(Quantity.SINGLE, Type.POST)
    MULTIPLE_GET(Quantity.MULTIPLE, Type.GET)
    // ... more options
    // contents same as in class Operation, constructor private by default
}
```

Both approaches are valid, sometimes you really want to enumerate all the combinations, most of the time, however, you should probably stick with the `class` approach.

For brevity, I didn't define the enums `Quantity` and `Type`, they are just simple enums.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all elements of `enum` are `static final constant`. 
However as mentioned in another answer by `darijan`, there is a logical mistake in your program.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in fourth line of `main` method

```
oper1.setOperation(Type.POST);
```

should be

```
oper2.setOperation(Type.POST);
```

Comment: that's typo in the code