# What's difference between enums and final variables?

Tags: java, enums

I am trying to read up on enums to better understand them.

From the javadocs of enums I get the following:

> An enum type is a special data type that enables for a variable to be a set of predefined constants.

To me this sounds a lot like a `final` variable.

1. What is the real difference?
2. And when would you use one over the other?
3. Is enum just a final variable that can be a set of things?

Comment: Also have a look at this thread [stackoverflow: are java enum variables static][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166668/are-java-enum-variables-static

Here it is explained also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have an `enum` like

```
public enum MyEnum {
   FIRST_COSTANT, SECOND_CONSTANT;
}
```

What you actually have is

```
public class /* enum */ MyEnum extends Enum<MyEnum> {
    private Enum() {}
    public final static MyEnum FIRST_CONSTANT = new MyEnum() {};
    public final static MyEnum SECOND_CONSTANT = new MyEnum() {};    
    ... // methods     
}
```

So in that sense, yes, they are the same.

This is explained in the Java Language Specification [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2).

> In addition to the members that an enum type E inherits from Enum,
>   **for each declared enum constant with the name n, the enum type has an
>   implicitly declared public static final field named n of type E**. These
>   fields are considered to be declared in the same order as the
>   corresponding enum constants, before any static fields explicitly
>   declared in the enum type. Each such field is initialized to the enum
>   constant that corresponds to it. Each such field is also considered to
>   be annotated by the same annotations as the corresponding enum
>   constant. The enum constant is said to be created when the
>   corresponding field is initialized.

Comment: each enum entry is a subclass, not a just instance

Answer (score 6):

The difference is that enums provide **type safety**.

Let's have this `enum`.

```
public enum MuEnum {
    FIRST("First"), SECOND("Second");

    private String value;

    MyEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Consider the following example:

```
public void myMethod(MyEnum parameter) { .. }
```

Here, you can only pass `MyEnum` values (`FIRST` or `SECOND`), while if your method signature was:

```
public void myMethod(String parameter) { .. }
```

you would be able to pass an invalid parameter (some `String` which content is different than `"First"` or `"Second"`).

Answer (score 3):

There is a big difference: first, `enum`, is not a variable, it is a type. A `final` variable, say, an `int`, can have a single, preset value from among many possible values of `int`, while an `enum` variable (which could also be `final`) can have a value from a set that you declare when defining the `enum`.

Here is an example:

```
enum Color {Red, Green, Blue;}
```

The declaration above does not define a variable. It defines a set of values a variable of type `Color` *could* have, if you choose to declare one:

```
Color backgroundColor = Color.Red;
```

Now you have a non-final variable of an enumerated type `Color`. Its value can change, but it must be one of the three values defined as part of the `enum`.

In practice, you use an `enum` when you model a something with a fixed number of states, to which you would like to give a name. You could use one or more `final` variables for that, too, - in fact, this has been done a lot before `enum`s were introduced. For example, Java's `Calendar` class uses `static final int` constants for the various parts of the date, where an `enum` would have worked better.

Answer (score 2):

I think enums are not final because you can define an anonymous subclass for each field inside of the enum descriptor.

From the docs:

> Enum types (§8.9) must not be declared abstract; doing so will result
>   in a compile-time error.
>
> An enum type is implicitly final unless it contains at least one enum
>   constant that has a class body.
>
> It is a compile-time error to explicitly declare an enum type to be
>   final.
>
> Nested enum types are implicitly static. It is permissible to
>   explicitly declare a nested enum type to be static.

**Also to mark a point that if we say a class as Final then it means that they can not be inherited. However, when it comes to enums then they can not be inherited by default.**

Answer (score 1):

In one way of thinking, yes. The following statements are roughly equivalent:

```
// This...
final int FIRST = 0;
final int SECOND = 1;

// Is roughly equivalent to this.
enum Ordering = { FIRST, SECOND };
```

The difference is type safety. Since the `Ordering` enum names a new type, you can have a function which takes an `Ordering` rather than an `int`. This ensures at compile time that you don't accidentally pass an out of bounds value (like 2) to a function expecting an `Ordering`.

```
void foo(Ordering order) {;}

foo(FIRST); // This works
foo(3); // This causes an error at compile time
```

Answer (score 0):

Enums are used for every case where you know how many instances of a type you will have. Yes, before enums, static final variables were used.

Enums provides a few niceties that simple static final variables do not have:

- They are typed.
- They come with some helpful methods like valueOf, that allows to look for them by their name, or to enumerate them.
- Each instance can override methods of an enum to provide a particular behaviour.
- Enum ensure that there will never be any other instance of the class than the ones defined, without having to set a constructor as private or other tricks that can be overcome by reflection. Therefore it is a nice way to implement some patterns like the Singleton pattern.