# Accessing superclass variables from an enum

Tags: java, object, enums, enumeration

Is there any way to set a variable held in an enums parent/superclass from within an enum itself?  (The following doesn't compile, but illustrates what I'm attempting to achieve)....

```
class MyClass{

    ObjectType type;        
    String someValue;


    public void setType(ObjectType thisType){

        type = thisType;

    } 

    enum ObjectType {

        ball{
            @Override
            public void setValue(){
                someValue = "This is a ball";  //Some value isn't accessible from here
            }
        },
        bat{
            @Override
            public void setValue(){
                someValue = "This is a bat";  //Some value isn't accessible from here
            }
        },

        net{
            @Override
            public void setValue(){
                someValue  = "This is a net";  //Some value isn't accessible from here
            }
        };

        public abstract void setValue();
    }

}
```

Then, something like so:

```
MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
myObject.setType(ObjectType.ball);
```

After doing the above, the 'someValue' string of the myObject should now be set to 'This is a ball'.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Storing state in an enum, or having that ability by making it look mutable, is a very bad idea. What you can do, though, is pass parameters in an enum's constructor. Take a look at the [Planet example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following, if you want MyClass.someValue to equal the someValue of the enum, but as someValue can be retrieved from the enum I'd not bother having someValue on MyClass at all, and just retrieve it from the enum when required

```
public class MyClass {
    ObjectType type;
    String someValue;

    public void setType(ObjectType thisType) {
        this.type = thisType;
        this.someValue = thisType.getSomeValue();
    }

    enum ObjectType {
        ball ("This is a ball"),
        bat ("This is a bat"),
        net ("This is a net");

        private final String someValue;

        ObjectType(String someValue) {
            this.someValue = someValue;
        }

        public String getSomeValue() {
            return someValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A nested `enum` type is implicitly static (see [Are java enum variables static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166668/are-java-enum-variables-static)). That includes `enum` types declared as inner classes, so they can't access instance fields of the outer class.

You can't do what you're trying to do with an `enum`, you'll have to model that as a normal class.

Comment: "so they can't access member fields of the outer class" if I remember correctly they can, but they need explicit instance of outer class, something like `public void setValue(MyClass mc){ mc.someValue = "This is a ball";}`.

Comment: You're right on not being able to set fields of an outer class, but that's fixed by doing `enum ObjectType extends MyClass`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You might be right, but it can definitely `implement` something.

Comment: @skaffman I said in my comment to the question that this is probably the wrong question to be asking. This is either an abuse of an enum or a valid use, but one that would be better off using the parametrized enum constructor.